# How to tuple with Member_Key MDX SSAS?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I want to tuple using member key of [Dim].[Country]

```
{[Dim].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Key},
STRTOSET("[User].[ID].&[" + mid(username, instr(username, "\")+1) + "]")
```

But when I use CurrentMember.Member_Key function I get the following error:
The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

If I write it like this using "members" is works. But then it will tuple with the full name (100 - Norway) but my goal is to tuple it with just the key part e.g "100"

```
{[Dim].[Country].members},
STRTOSET("[User].[ID].&[" + mid(username, instr(username, "\")+1) + "]")
```

Best regards,
Rubrix

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [Dim].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Key you should do something like this:

```
with member [Measures].CountryKey as [Dim].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Key
```

So something like this could work (on Adventure Works):

```
with member [Measures].CountryKey as [Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Key
SELECT ([Measures].CountryKey, StrToSet ('[Geography].[State-Province].Members')  )
ON 0  
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: This is inside Visual studios in the OLAP cube in the Data dimension tab for a Role, so I am not really sure how to create the [Measures].CountryKey.
See this blog post:
http://bifuture.blogspot.com/2011/09/ssas-setup-dynamic-security-in-analysis.html

Comment: I have created the example in the blog which works great for one of my Dimension attributes [Country code] since in the security table the column being used is [Country Code]. The issue is that I also have an attribute in the same dimension that I wish to apply the same security to but this attribute is [Country Code_Description] which doesnt match the security table. What I did for the [Country Code_Description] was that I set the KeyColumn to [Country Code] so that I could use the Member_Key.

Comment: But then this statement doesn't work.
{[Dim].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Key},
STRTOSET("[User].[ID].&[" + mid(username, instr(username, "\")+1) + "]")

Comment: My first thought was that I had to substring the description part from [Country Code_Description]
That is why I posted: "How to remove all characters after first space for OLAP dimension members"